# joining to a table that might not exist

Tags: sql

So I have joined a table to itself in order to find the most recently added note of a certain type (;NoteTypesID=20625;). BUT when there is NOTHING of that type, it completely excludes the entire record's results from my dataset, instead of giving me nulls for the fields I am trying to pull from the ;PROPOSALNOTEPAD; table.

```
---select ... from ... (including the prop table)

left join PROPOSALNOTEPAD PN_SolicitationStrategy on prop.ID = PN_SolicitationStrategy.ParentId 
   
   join ( select parentID, max(DateAdded) as MaxDateAdded FROM PROPOSAL_NOTEPAD where NoteTypeID = 20625  group by ParentId) as PN_max_SolicitationStrategy 

  ON PN_SolicitationStrategy.ParentId = PN_max_SolicitationStrategy.ParentId AND PN_SolicitationStrategy.DateAdded = PN_max_SolicitationStrategy.MaxDateAdded
```

I need to be able to test if this is null: ;select parentID FROM PROPOSAL_NOTEPAD where NoteTypeID = 20625;. And then do my joins based on that result. How do I do that? How do I join based on a condition?

Comment: Use a left join for your select.

Comment: So easy! Thanks! I had tried that and didn't think it worked, but tried again and added another piece of logic and got it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
left join PROPOSALNOTEPAD PN_SolicitationStrategy on prop.ID = PN_SolicitationStrategy.ParentId 
   
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ( select parentID, max(DateAdded) as MaxDateAdded FROM PROPOSAL_NOTEPAD where NoteTypeID = 20625  group by ParentId) as PN_max_SolicitationStrategy 

  ON PN_SolicitationStrategy.ParentId = PN_max_SolicitationStrategy.ParentId AND PN_SolicitationStrategy.DateAdded = PN_max_SolicitationStrategy.MaxDateAdded
```

Inner Join always brings the common records from both table. In your case, there is no matching record from 1st table and PN_max_SolicitationStrategy table. That's why you are getting no records.

Using **LEFT OUTER JOIN** will bring you all the records from 1st table and matching records from the 2nd (PN_max_SolicitationStrategy) table.

Here is simple tutorial to learn about JOINs: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp